# Getting ANR when GLThread is very busy and the application is in background

Tags: android, opengl-es, background, android-anr-dialog

I've noticed the following weird behaviour when my GLThread is doing an intensive work.

Launch the application and wait until the GLThread does an intensive task.
Send the application to background
Send a push notification from firebase
Wait until ANR show up (because the application cannot wake up the Notification Service)

If instead of sending the application to background I just wait with the application in foreground, the notification arrives and the ANR does not show up.

In theory GLThread is not the main thread so I should be able to do any kind of work in there without getting an ANR.

You can find my project here:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/113119768

In order to reproduce my "intensive work" i just put an infinite loop on the onDrawFrame Function

```
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    while(true)
    {
        Log.e("GLThread", "draw");
    }
}
```

Any help would be very appreciated.